# Disable finding repository root in parent directories

Tags: git

So I'm a `Linux` user and I got this weird setup where my home directory itself is a repository. I use `.gitignore` to include only what I want in this repository. Goal is to manage user configuration easily.

```
.
+-- home
|   +-- user           <- (this is a git repository)
|       +-- .config
|       +-- workspace
|           +-- git project 1
|           +-- git project 2
|           +-- NOT git project 1
```

Now the issue is when I'm working on simple scripts or what ever, I don't use git and I'll be in somewhere in `workspace` directory. I'm worried that I will mistakenly reset the repository. In that case it's going to reset changes in my home directory. Can I configure `git` not to go looking for root repository and to work only if it finds `.git` in the current directory?

Answer (score 1):

One possible trick would be to declare a git repository in workspace itself.

Even if you are not using Git in workspace, any Git command would be limited to workspace and below, and would be go above workspace.